# Ubuntu 20.10 cannot disable IPv6 via sysctl

Tags: networking, ipv6

The title says it all. I have been going over and over this for a few hours now, to no avail.

```
root@blueberry:~# cat /etc/sysctl.d/no-ipv6-please.conf
net.ipv6.conf.all.autoconf = 0
net.ipv6.conf.all.disable_ipv6 = 1
net.ipv6.conf.default.disable_ipv6 = 1
net.ipv6.conf.eth0.disable_ipv6 = 1
net.ipv6.conf.lo.disable_ipv6 = 1
net.ipv6.conf.wlan0.disable_ipv6 = 1
net.ipv6.conf.all.autoconf = 0
net.ipv6.conf.default.autoconf = 0
net.ipv6.conf.eth0.autoconf = 0
net.ipv6.conf.lo.autoconf = 0
net.ipv6.conf.wlan0.autoconf = 0
root@blueberry:~# for z in `awk  '{ print $1 }' /etc/sysctl.d/no-ipv6-please.conf`; do sysctl $z; done
net.ipv6.conf.all.autoconf = 0
net.ipv6.conf.all.disable_ipv6 = 1
net.ipv6.conf.default.disable_ipv6 = 1
net.ipv6.conf.eth0.disable_ipv6 = 0
net.ipv6.conf.lo.disable_ipv6 = 1
net.ipv6.conf.wlan0.disable_ipv6 = 0
net.ipv6.conf.all.autoconf = 0
net.ipv6.conf.default.autoconf = 0
net.ipv6.conf.eth0.autoconf = 0
net.ipv6.conf.lo.autoconf = 0
net.ipv6.conf.wlan0.autoconf = 0
root@blueberry:~#
```

Ubuntu version:

```
root@blueberry:~# uname -a
Linux blueberry 5.8.0-1006-raspi #9-Ubuntu SMP PREEMPT Fri Oct 16 12:55:30 UTC 2020 aarch64 aarch64 aarch64 GNU/Linux
root@blueberry:~# cat /etc/os-release
NAME="Ubuntu"
VERSION="20.10 (Groovy Gorilla)"
ID=ubuntu
ID_LIKE=debian
PRETTY_NAME="Ubuntu 20.10"
VERSION_ID="20.10"
HOME_URL="https://www.ubuntu.com/"
SUPPORT_URL="https://help.ubuntu.com/"
BUG_REPORT_URL="https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/"
PRIVACY_POLICY_URL="https://www.ubuntu.com/legal/terms-and-policies/privacy-policy"
VERSION_CODENAME=groovy
UBUNTU_CODENAME=groovy
root@blueberry:~#
```

Wifi:

```
root@blueberry:~# ip addr sh wlan0
3: wlan0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether <mac address> brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.178.67/24 brd 192.168.178.255 scope global wlan0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 <address>/64 scope global dynamic mngtmpaddr noprefixroute
       valid_lft 6969sec preferred_lft 3369sec
    inet6 <address>/64 scope global dynamic mngtmpaddr noprefixroute
       valid_lft 5702sec preferred_lft 2102sec
    inet6 <address>/64 scope link
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
root@blueberry:~#
```

The machine is a Raspberry Pi, if that helps.

Now, before anybody comments disabling IPv6 is "such a bad idea", I need to remove everything that are unused along with some hardening. Disabling IPv6 used to be a trivial task, does sysctl have no more control?

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: What happens when you run `sysctl -p /etc/sysctl.d/no-ipv6-please.conf`?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and solved it by putting the line: `link-local: [ipv4]` within the block of proper interface in the `/etc/netplan/50-cloud-init.yaml` file. Then: "netplan reload" or full restart.
I have no idea if this is proper, supported and "sanctified" way to manipulate network settings in Ubuntu 20.10, but it seems to be the right way right way.